# bigquery does not load JSON

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this JSON:

```json
{'category':'runtime_exception',
'action':"Cannot read property 'isCurrentlySorted' of undefined",
'value':'TypeError: Cannot read property "isCurrentlySorted" of undefined    at Ht.SetSectionCurrentlySorted',
'current_url':'/drugs-list',
'serial_number':'A4001-2816',
'session_id':null,
'timeStamp':'2021-08-10T14:11:10.309Z',
'localTimeStamp':'Tue Aug 10 2021 17:11:10 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)',
'user':{'machine':null,'info':{'user_id':'yuval.haliva@eitanmedical.com'}},
'event_id':9}
```

When uploading it to bigquery, I get this error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: No such field: category.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. Here is a quick overview for basic JSON syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

In short, use double quotes (`"`) to encapsulate your keys and values instead of single quotes (`'`). There are a lot of online JSON validators out there. Here is an example: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It auto-corrects your JSON to:

```json
{
   "category":"runtime_exception",
   "action":"Cannot read property 'isCurrentlySorted' of undefined",
   "value":"TypeError: Cannot read property \"isCurrentlySorted\" of undefined    at Ht.SetSectionCurrentlySorted",
   "current_url":"/drugs-list",
   "serial_number":"A4001-2816",
   "session_id":null,
   "timeStamp":"2021-08-10T14:11:10.309Z",
   "localTimeStamp":"Tue Aug 10 2021 17:11:10 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)",
   "user":{
      "machine":null,
      "info":{
         "user_id":"yuval.haliva@eitanmedical.com"
      }
   },
   "event_id":9
}
```